# How to import an XEN disk.raw VM into OracleVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, oraclevm

I have two virtual machines running on an OpenSuse 12.3 Linux with XEN. These VMs has disk.raw files with Linux running inside them. I'm trying to use Oracle VM and want to get the two XEN disk.raw files imported to Oracle VM hypervisor with OracleVM Manager and I couldn't do it. Whem I google about this I found that Oracle VM is based on XEN. But I can't find how to put my XEN VMs into Oracle VM.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask help maybe can be useful if you give some information more,i never used oracle vm manager, copy vm disk files with scp from one server to an other and the configuration files, aster that try to start the vm guest with xm command or in new xen version xe command

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the two VMs installed as Xen guests (DomU) on separate disk partitions, you should copy the disk.raw files onto the machine where you've installed Oracle VM, and create a new virtual machine for both of them using `virt-install` as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11081_01/doc/doc.21/e10898/createvm.htm#insertedID4), and provide the disk.raw files as the storage for the VMs in Step 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualBox to create an OVF formatted virtual machine or virtual machine assembly, which are the preferred ways of deploying virtual machines on Oracle VM Server.

1. Convert disk images with qemu if required and import them into VirtualBox.
2. Create a VM and attach the disks.
3. Export as OVF if you prefer multiple files over creating a template, otherwise export as OVA.
4. Import the resulting VM or VM assembly into Oracle VM and deploy the VM.